# VBA: Could not write cell values to text file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an existing excel worksheet with data that is something like this:

```
Col A  Col B        Col C
123    17/1/1993    ABC
124    18/1/1993    DEF
125    19/1/1993    AAD
126    20/1/1993    AIG
127    21/1/1993    GBI
```

I want to write the data into a tab-delimited text file. With the following code, the text file created does not contain the values in the cells, although the tabs are written to the text file.

```
Sub writetotext()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcol As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim celldata As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim fso As Object

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\textoutput.txt"
    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    lastcol =        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fname)

    For i = 1 To lastrow
        For j = 1 To lastcol
            If j = lastcol Then
                celldata = celldata + ActiveCell(i, j).Value
            Else
                celldata = celldata + ActiveCell(i, j).Value + vbTab
            End If
        Next j
        objFile.writeline celldata
        celldata = ""
    Next i

    objFile.Close

End Sub
```

Seems like ActiveCell(i, j).Value does not work, but I don't know how to rectify this problem. I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: `ActiveCell(i, j).Value` **does** work, but it just isn't what you want to use.  E.g. `ActiveCell(2, 4)` refers to the cell 1 row below, and 3 columns to the right of, the active cell and, if the active cell is D56 then that means it is referring to G57.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can greatly reduce the length of your code by means of:

- arrays and [their slicing methods](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/)
- instantiating a `FileSystemObject` file object "on the fly"

like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub writetotext()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dataArr As Variant

    dataArr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value '<--| store all values in an array
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\textoutput.txt") '<--| instantiate a 'FileSystemObject' file object and reference it
        For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1) '<--| loop through data array rows
            .writeline Join(Application.Index(dataArr, i, 0), vbTab) '<--| write current data array row values joined with vbtab delimeter
        Next i
        .Close '<--| close referenced instance of the 'FileSystemObject' file object
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @peejayjay, did you get through it?

Comment: Yup I tried this and it greatly reduced my lines of code! But a problem I have with this is when writing data with large rows (>30000) to text file. The computational speed is too slow

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `ActiveCell(i, j)` with `Cells(i, j)`.

Also, to combine the text use `&` and not `+`, so your line should actualy look like `celldata = celldata & Cells(i, j).Value & vbTab`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub writetotext()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim celldata As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim fso As Object, objFile As Object

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\textoutput.txt"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    lastrow = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    lastcol = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fname)

    With ws
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            For j = 1 To lastcol
                If j = lastcol Then
                    celldata = celldata & .Cells(i, j).Value
                Else
                    celldata = celldata & .Cells(i, j).Value & vbTab
                End If
            Next j
            objFile.writeline celldata
            celldata = ""
        Next i
    End With

    objFile.Close

End Sub
```